# How to shedule a request for location update in Android from a service

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

this scenario is very common according to the Android documentation but still I don't find a straight solution neither there nor anywhere on the net.
So I have a service that should do something like this:

1. Register a LocationListener to receive the user location
2. Once the LocationListener is called - stop listening for a 5 minutes
3. After 5 minutes start listening again and loop from 1

This is the recommended way to save battery power while listening for the user location.

As a service I have a major problem with step 3. 
The only way I found to "wait" for 5 minutes is to schedule a java.util.Timer to execute a TimerTask in 5 minutes and this TimerTask should register the LocationListneres again.
However this does not work because of:
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()** 
Which is also expected because requestLocationUpdates should be called from a "main" thread.

Ok .. nice... but I don't have a Main thread. I don't have an activity. From the TimerTask I can't send an intent to the service to register my listeners back.

How can I ask my own service to register my listeners again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the recommended way to save battery power while listening for the user location.

Really? The only way that's a good pattern is if you are using `AlarmManager` for the five-minute delay, so the device falls asleep in between location checks.

> The only way I found to "wait" for 5 minutes is to schedule a java.util.Timer to execute a TimerTask in 5 minutes and this TimerTask should register the LocationListneres again.

And that would be a horrible use of battery, because it would mean you would need to keep the device powered on constantly, not allowing it to go to sleep.

> I don't have a Main thread

Yes, you do. All processes have a main application thread. `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, etc. of a service are called on the main application thread.

> I don't have an activity.

Then you better write one, as your app will not work on Android 3.1+ without it. Your app will not run until a user launches one of your activities on Android 3.1+.

> How can I ask my own service to register my listeners again?

What you are trying to accomplish is a rather complex problem. Not only do you need to arrange for the device to fall asleep and wake back up again, but you also need to deal with lots of edge cases (e.g., what if no location is available, because the device is in airplane mode or is underground or something?).

I wrote [`LocationPoller`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-locpoll) to handle your use case, and another developer [forked it to create a more feature-rich implementation](https://github.com/alexbirkett/cwac-locpoll).

Whether you use one of these directly or simply examine their implementation, they should be useful to help you understand how to solve this problem. All of the details, though, are well beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer -- it would take several pages in a book to explain it all.

Comment: Thanks - the referenced coding gives me a good start to develop further my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the parameter in `requeestLocationUpdates()` to make it run after a certain time.